# What commercial (brick and mortar) banks support ADA staking?

Tags: money

Some online banks have started allowing trade in ADA. None of these banks seem to offer staking. I understand the argument for self-management and decentralisation (if large exchanges start staking) but some users might not want the burdon of self-management.

What banks / online trading platforms, support staking?

Comment: This is not a technical question about the Cardano network but about the social context surrounding it, which can change over time.

Answer (score 2):

Binance is the only leading exchange which offers staking that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks. 

Binance - from what I've seen offer minimal staking at this point.

Comment: Coinbase does not support ADA. Only four coins can be staked currently according to their site: https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/staking/staking-on-coinbase
Algorand
Cosmos 
Ethereum
Tezos

Comment: You're right @rubikwall, I misread their site. Edited and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There aren’t any commercial (brick and mortar) banks that support Ada staking. Banks are the “middle man,” crypto is designed to remove the “middle man” from the equation. Banks are antithetical to the whole ethos of the cryptocurrency movement.

Comment: SwissQuote (Switzerland) will support ADA staking by year end.